# Suggestion: location of jobs in the experience section of the CV on careers site

Tags: feature-request, jobs, location, experience

Location seems like something worth adding here.

Comment: I was drafting up this very feature request.  I agree wholeheartedly.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a traditional thing on a resume, and adds "color", so I think it's worth adding