# Add location(s) to StackOverflow careers experience/job history

Tags: feature-request, jobs, experience

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestion: location of jobs in the experience section of the CV on careers site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25035/suggestion-location-of-jobs-in-the-experience-section-of-the-cv-on-careers-site)

On the StackOverflow careers site, it would be useful to be able to specify the location(s) at which you have worked for any of your experience/job history items.